# Software for a real-world simulation of a radio link

Tags: simulation, wifi, radio

Is there any open source software/library (in any language) that can perform real-world simulations of a radio link?

For "radio link" I mean the connection between two 5.8 GHz wifi modems, each modem is connected to an antenna with a particular radiation pattern, the antennas are in the real world so they are described by their GPS position and their orientation in space.

The software that I'm looking for has to at least give me the value of the signal strength of the wifi connection, it doesn't have to simulate also the wifi protocol itself, I don't care about the actual data transmitted.